# Как обойти сервер когда он банит за большое количество запросов?

Tags: php, laravel

```
$dom = HtmlDomParser::file_get_html($page, false, null, 0)->find(".leftcol .area .listItem");
```

За большого количества запросов сервер банит и не отдает html (403)
Как можно решить проблему?
Читал что возможно прокси может помочь но как это реализовать? и поможет?

Comment: Читайте про Curl, и прокси.

Comment: либо ходите через разные прокси, либо увеличьте интервал между запросами. Чтобы не лезть в дебри HtmlDom скачайте страницу штатными средствами `file_get_contents/curl` используя прокси, а потом результат уже библиотеке скормите.

Comment: Делать меньше запросов, очевидно

Comment: Изменяйте при каждом запросе user-agent , может помочь.